# Javascript Form: Only Changed Fields

Tags: javascript

I have a php-site with a form on which i output preselected values via php. On form submit I want to check which values have changed and just submit these via javascript.

These are the preselected values I passed over from php. It's important that I keep the associative array structure.

```
var pbData = jQuery.parseJSON("{
"GameMode":"DEATHMATCH",
"Current Map":"VEGAS JUNKYARD",
"Current Missions":["VEGAS JUNKYARD","VILLA","PRESIDIO","KILL HOUSE","MURDERTOWN","CQB TRAINING","STREETS","THREE KINGDOMS CASINO","IMPORT\/EXPORT;"],
"RoundDuration":"3 minutes"}");
```

I marked the error in the code.

```
<script>
function displayVars(){
var form = document.getElementById('settings');
var elems = form.elements;
var txt = "";
for (var index = 0; index < elems.length; index++){
    var selIndex = elems[index].selectedIndex;
    if (typeof selIndex !== "undefined"){
        //the Index Name in the json-object and the name of the form-field are the same 
        var idxName = elems[index].name;
//HERE is the problem. I want to access the subobject via a variablename, so i can iterate through it, but that doesnt work.
        console.log ("pbData default = "+pbData.idxName); //always undefined
        if (elems[index].value !== pbData.idx_name){
            //building a POST-Url
            txt = txt + elems[index].name + "=" + elems[index].options[selIndex].value+"&";
        }
    }
}
console.log (txt);
return false;
}
</script>
```

I know that I could do this differently, also with jQuery. In my case as I have the preselected values as a php-variable in any case, i think it's easier like this.
I would really like to know how I can iterate through the subobjects via a variable that contains the object names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how you'e trying to access the property of the (JSON) object. Consider

```
var o1 = {idxName: true},
    o2 = {foo : 'bar'},
    idxName = 'foo';

o1.idxName;  // true
o2.idxName;  // undefined
o2[idxName]; // 'bar'
```

You need to access the property via `pbData[idxName]`.

---

Additionally, you're not escaping quotes in your JSON string, and line breaks need to be escaped as follows

```
var pbData = jQuery.parseJSON("{\
\"GameMode\":\"DEATHMATCH\",\
\"Current Map\":\"VEGAS JUNKYARD\",\
\"Current Missions\":[\"VEGAS JUNKYARD\",\"VILLA\",\"PRESIDIO\",\"KILL HOUSE\",\"MURDERTOWN\",\"CQB TRAINING\",\"STREETS\",\"THREE KINGDOMS CASINO\",\"IMPORT\/EXPORT;\"],\
\"RoundDuration\":\"3 minutes\"}");
```

Comment: I escaped the "" in php and now I can access the values properly. Thx

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you could keep an object or array with initial values and only post those values that are changed.

But in fact, I would do something similar, but in PHP. You can keep the original values in the session and compare the posted values to those initial values to see what has changed. That way, you won't depend on Javascript. Not only may Javascript be disabled, but also, a fast user may theoretically post the form before the Javascript has run. To move this check to PHP eliminates that risk.